# Weka, which classifier to use, for two categorical and 10 numerical attributes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, naivebayes

I would like to ask, I have 10 columns with sound parameters and after 2 columns with which two instrument was recorded in this moment.

After I have data with 10 columns of sound parameters and I need to predict which single instrument was used.

I know about data pre processing and so on, but I would like to double check if I'm choosing the right classified. For the example I provided, would be appropriate to use, Naïve Bayes or Linear Regression or SVN?? I just confused which will be more appropriate for this particular example.

Comment: why don't you try all of them and choose the one with the better results?

Comment: @xro7 "Your submission will be evaluated using the classification error." -  any thinking about most appropriate?

Comment: i don't know which is the best for your case but you could have already trained all three classifiers and choose the one with the smallest classification error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to predict which one will work best on *your* data.

Every data set is different. Sometimes A is better, sometimes B.

Therefore, try all of them, and use cross-validation to check which worked best.